# Практика Javascript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, изучаю JavaScript по книге Дэвида Флэнагана, но очень не хватает практики, что можете посоветовать по этому поводу?

Comment: Больше программировать. Практика - дело наживное.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-моему, довольно интересно программировать всякую графику: повторяющиеся паттерны, псевдослучайные элементы. Попробуйте писать разные этюды, результатами которых будут картинки. Для этого может понадобиться библиотека для работы с SVG, напр. [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) (на этой же страницы примеры для вдохновления), или [D3js](http://d3js.org/).

Comment: из практического задания можно [вот это](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.4279v2.pdf) например реализовать

Comment: Raphaёl немного забросили, сейчас вроде kinetics и d3(для обработки даты) на коне

Comment: @eicto: спасибо за паттерны!

Comment: Рекомендовать Processing как практику JS - странно, другой язык совсем ведь.

Comment: @Shock: вы правы. Ошибочно полагал, что скетчи P.js пишутся на JS. Оказалось, нет - та же Java, что и в просто-Processing. Редактирую ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Не знаю этой книги и не являюсь разработчиком с опытом. Но соетую пройти обучение данного интернет-учебника: [javascript.ru/tutorial](http://javascript.ru/tutorial)

Там много примеров, разъяснений и советов к применению.

Comment: >Не знаю этой книги и не являюсь разработчиком с опытом.
А я знаю и являюсь и могу подтвердить сказанное...

Answer (score 3):

Напишите 3d змейку с использованием [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте создать что ни будь экспериментируйте. Что то не получается!? Ищите решение проблемы (кстати здесь отличное место для этого или [Google](http://google.com/)) Я например начал с крестиков ноликов и теперь разрабатываю [WebWin API](http://webwin.hostoi.com/) ...

Answer (score 0):

В наше время, учить javascript и при этом не подтянуть html, css и популярные фреймворки (в стиле jQuery) просто бессмысленно. Поэтому, параллельно с книжкой рекомендую пойти на [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/) и методично прорабатывать уроки для выработки автоматизма.

Comment: на CodeAcademy много плохих практик и мало сути, кроме того изучать язык as is не бессмысленно, желательно в отрыве от DOMа

Comment: может просто их не осилили?

А изучать язык в отрыве от родной среды как то неверно. для javascript я знаю только ещё nodejs и rhino, но там все равно нужно знать DOM, просто свой.

Comment: > DOM, просто свой

???

Comment: Поправил слово DOM в кавычки, что бы не делать с него красную тряпку:)

в том же nodejs никто не мешает загрузить xml и парсить, но также там есть свое дерево внутренних переменных, которые можно расценить как некое подобие dom.

В rhino, который используется в java, внешний код может предоставлять свой набор внешних классов, которые можно трактовать как dom.

Comment: @KoVadim, если мыслить так как вы, то в C тоже есть DOM ибо тоже можно спарсить XML :)

Comment: да, там тоже может быть, но он будет по большей части очень локальным.

Comment: @KoVadim я смотрел CodeAcademy на предмет того, чтобы отсылать туда ньюфагов, пришел к выводу, что примерно тоже самое что w3schools по качесту

Answer (score 0):

http://beta.javascript.ru/

Вот тут куча практики.

Answer (score 0):

Решайте задачи по программированию. По JavaScript задачи Вы вряд ли найдете. Можно искать задачи на языках, похожих по синтаксису на JavaScript. Например Ruby, Java.

Comment: Совет хороший, но: Java похож по синтаксису на Javascript? Ну...

    (function(x) {
        alert([0,, , 3, 5, { who: "framed", roger: /rab*it/g }]);
    })();